# How to make groups in a data.frame equal length?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c('A','A','B','B','B','C'), amount=c(45,66,99,34,71,22))

id | amount 
-----------
A  |   45   
A  |   66   
B  |   99
B  |   34 
B  |   71
C  |   22
```

which I need to expand so that each `by` group in the data.frame is of equal length (filling it out with zeroes), like so:

```
id | amount 
-----------
A  |   45   
A  |   66  
A  |   0     <- added 
B  |   99
B  |   34 
B  |   71
C  |   22
C  |   0     <- added 
C  |   0     <- added
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

**NOTE**

Benchmarking the some of the solutions provided with my *actual* 1 million row data.frame I got:

```
             plyr   | data.table  |  unstack
          -----------------------------------
Elapsed:   139.87s  |    0.09s    |   2.00s
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way using `data.table`

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), 
          .Label = c("A  ", "B  ", "C  "), class = "factor"), 
          V2 = c(45, 66, 99, 34, 71, 22)), 
          .Names = c("V1", "V2"), 
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df, key="V1")

# get maximum index
idx <- max(dt[, .N, by=V1]$N)

# get final result
dt[, list(V2 = c(V2, rep(0, idx-length(V2)))), by=V1]

#     V1 V2
# 1: A   45
# 2: A   66
# 3: A    0
# 4: B   99
# 5: B   34
# 6: B   71
# 7: C   22
# 8: C    0
# 9: C    0
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure there is a base R solution, but here is one that uses `ddply` in the `plyr` package

```
library(plyr)
##N: How many values should be in each group
N = 3
ddply(df, "id", summarize, 
      amount = c(amount, rep(0, N-length(amount))))
```

gives:

```
  id amount
1  A     45
2  A     66
3  A      0
4  B     99
5  B     34
6  B     71
7  C     22
8  C      0
9  C      0
```

Comment: As long as `N` is the maximum you don't need a `max` there?

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way in base R using `unstack` and `stack`.

```
# ensure character id col
df <- transform(df, id=as.character(id))
# break into a list by id
u <- unstack(df, amount ~ id)
# get max length
max.len <- max(sapply(u, length))
# pad the short ones with 0s
filled <- lapply(u, function(x) c(x, numeric(max.len - length(x))))
# recombine into data.frame
stack(filled)

#   values ind
# 1     45   A
# 2     66   A
# 3      0   A
# 4     99   B
# 5     34   B
# 6     71   B
# 7     22   C
# 8      0   C
# 9      0   C
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
out <- by(df, INDICES = df$id, FUN = function(x, N) {
  x <- droplevels(x)
  lng <- nrow(x)
  dif <- N - lng
  if (dif == 0) return(x)
  make.list <- lapply(1:dif, FUN = function(y) data.frame(id = levels(x$id), amount = 0))
  rbind(x, do.call("rbind", make.list))
  }, N = max(table(df$id))) # N could also be an integer
do.call("rbind", out)

    id amount
A.1  A     45
A.2  A     66
A.3  A      0
B.3  B     99
B.4  B     34
B.5  B     71
C.6  C     22
C.2  C      0
C.3  C      0
```

Comment: Got this: `Error in data.frame(id = levels(x$id), amount = 0) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1`

Comment: Add `browser()` right before `droplevels()` and go through the function step-by-step and see where it went wrong. I've tried your example and it worked...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `dplyr` option:

```
library(dplyr)

# Get maximum number of rows for all groups
N = max(count(df,id)$n)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(amount = c(amount, rep(0, N-length(amount))), .groups = "drop")
```

**Output**

```
  id    amount
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 A         45
2 A         66
3 A          0
4 B         99
5 B         34
6 B         71
7 C         22
8 C          0
9 C          0
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use `complete` from `tidyr`. We create a row number column for each `id`, expand the observations and replace empty values with 0.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number(), .by = id) %>%
  complete(id, row, fill = list(amount = 0)) %>%
  select(-row)

#  id    amount
#  <chr>  <dbl>
#1 A         45
#2 A         66
#3 A          0
#4 B         99
#5 B         34
#6 B         71
#7 C         22
#8 C          0
#9 C          0
```